# how to convert foreach loop into for loop in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

```
foreach (Process newprcs in oPrcs)
 {
  newprocid = (UInt32)newprcs.Id;
  if (!oNewProcs.Contains(newprocid))  //checking process id contain or not
    {
      oNewProcs.Add(newprocid);
      // MessageBox.Show(newprocid.ToString());
      uIdOfProcess = newprocid;
      //MessageBox.Show(uIdOfProcess.ToString(),"ProcessId");
      CInjector.HookingAPI(uIdOfProcess, "HookPrintAPIs.dll");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the type of `oPrcs`. If it's a `Process[]` then it would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oPrcs.Length; i++)
{
    Process newprcs = oPrcs[i];
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, if the type of `oPrcs` implements `IEnumerable<Process>` (which it doesn't *have* to, admittedly - but it normally would) you'd get:

```
using (IEnumerator<Process> iterator = oPrcs.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        Process newprcs = iterator.Current;
        ...
    }
}
```

Having said all that, I usually *wouldn't* convert a `foreach` loop into a `for` loop...

Comment: +1 I rather throw in a counter somewhere if indexing is needed.

Comment: Would you convert a foreach into a for loop if you get this error: “Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.”

Comment: @MikeBarnes: I would usually try to work out why I was getting that, and avoid it. Just changing it into a `for` loop would still be potentially dangerous.

Comment: @JonSkeet the error occurs when I try and add something to a Dictionary in a foreach. I only get the error when I loop over the second item. Going to create a stack post now.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `oPrcs` is an `IList<Process>` (so it has a `Count` property and items can be accessed by index):

```
for (int i = 0; i < oPrcs.Count; i++)
{
    Process newprcs = oPrcs[i];
    if (!oNewProcs.Contains(newprocid))  //checking process id contain or not
    {
        oNewProcs.Add(newprocid);
        // MessageBox.Show(newprocid.ToString());
        uIdOfProcess = newprocid;
        //MessageBox.Show(uIdOfProcess.ToString(),"ProcessId");
        CInjector.HookingAPI(uIdOfProcess, "HookPrintAPIs.dll");
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to what FM said, it depends on what sort of collection you have. All collections supported by foreach do not have a Count or Length property.